# How to compare positions in sfml?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm new to sfml and I'm making a simple game. I need to compare 2 positions and I can't find how to do it.
How can I do it? I though that I can do it somehow like this:
`if (somesprite.getPosition() < (some x,some y)) { some code}`
So I just need to find out how to compare two positions.

Thank you in advance for answers that will get me closer to finding the right way to do it.
                                                                         - Torsmel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPosition()` returns a `sf::Vector2<T>` which has overloads for subtraction.
Subtract one `sf::Vector2<T>` from another and the length of the resulting `sf::Vector2<T>` will be the distance between the positions.

```
#include <SFML/System/Vector2.hpp>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T>
T Vector2length(const sf::Vector2<T>& v) {
    return std::sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);
}

void some_func() {
    auto spos = somesprite.getPosition();
    decltype(spos) xy(some_x, some_y);
    auto distance_vec = spos - xy;

    if( Vector2length(distance_vec) < max_distance ) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Since `sf::Vector2<T>` is lacking `length()` and other common functions usually associated with Cartesian vectors, an alternative to the above is to inherit `sf::Vector2<T>` and extend it:

```
#include <SFML/System/Vector2.hpp>
#include <cmath>

// extending sf::Vector2<T> with functions that could be nice to have
template<typename T>
struct Vector2_ext : sf::Vector2<T> {
    using sf::Vector2<T>::Vector2;
    // converting from a sf::Vector2
    Vector2_ext(const sf::Vector2<T>& o) : sf::Vector2<T>(o) {}

    // converting back to a sf::Vector2
    operator sf::Vector2<T>&() { return *this; }
    operator sf::Vector2<T> const&() const { return *this; }

    // your utility functions
    T length() const { return std::sqrt(this->x * this->x + this->y * this->y); }
};

// deduction guide
template<typename T>
Vector2_ext(T, T)->Vector2_ext<T>;
```

With this, you can convert back and forth between `sf::Vector2<T>` and `Vector2_ext<T>` when needed.

```
int some_func(sf::Sprite& somesprite, float some_x, float some_y, float max_distance) {
    auto distance =
        // somesprite.getPosition() - sf::Vector2(some_x, some_y) returns a sf::Vector2<T>
        // that we convert to a temporary Vector2_ext<T> and call its length() function:
        Vector2_ext(somesprite.getPosition() - sf::Vector2(some_x, some_y)).length();

    if(distance < max_distance) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: It throws me this error: Show link to compiled template T instance instances Vector2length <float> (const sf :: Vector2 <T> &)                                                   1> with                                                                                                                                                                1> [                                                                                                                              1> T = float                                                                                                               1>]

Comment: @Torsmel I made a small change and I've now tested that it works for me.

Comment: @Torsmel After looking closer at `sf::Vector2` I think I'd go for the alternative solution that I just added.